# UbuntuShowdown apps installation unable to locate package error

Tags: installation, ppa, repository

I recently heard about UbuntuShowdown apps. There are some very nice apps which I really want to try. I am trying to install these apps by adding repositories as it is mentioned on their page. But at the completion of command, it is showing:

```
unable to locate package <package name>
```

For example, after running this command in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brianrobles204/xkcd-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xkcd-browser
```

I am getting this at the end

```
unable to locate package xkcd-browser
```

Please help.

[UbuntuShowDown Apps](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppDevelopers/AppShowdown/CommunityVote#Applications)

Comment: The command is `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brianrobles204/xkcd-browser; sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xkcd-browser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work simply because the address doesn't exist, the PPA only has  1 package and it's for Precise not for Oneiric. Contact the maintainer and ask for an Oneiric package if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake with the command:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brianrobles204/xkcd-browser
 sudo apt-get update 
 sudo apt-get install xkcd-browser
```

It should be:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brianrobles204/xkcd-browser
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xkcd-browser
```

Hope this solves it!

Comment: thanks for your response...but now i am getting this error..i think i have to wait till these apps intergrated with Ubuntu software center.
Error--


W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/markus-lanner/blubphone/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/schumifer/postman/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: I tried those commands for different apps like postman, bluephone , facebook but it is showing the same thing- 404 not found

Comment: Make sure not to add the semicolon `;` at the end of the `ppa` or any of the commands for that matter

Comment: Ok, I got the same error for one of them

Comment: Ok, sorry for my answer, the commands that they give are correct. I did manage to install `xkcd-browser` and `postman`. I guess some ppa's might not work

Comment: it's ok.i really appreciate your responses,that too in short span of time..sooner or later things will work!!

Comment: @cgubuntu1204 There is nothing wrong with the commands, both ways work. `&&` serves to tell a command to execute the next command upon finishing the first one succesfully.